# In Google App Scripts How can you get the group name with the group email

Tags: google-apps-script

I have several alias's for my Google Groups.  The Google console search is really bad and won't return the group if just type of the email address.  I wanted to use Google App Script to pass the email address and have it return the name of the group.  Simple right.  I have not been able to find an SDK that actually returns the Google Group Name.  I have samples that tell me whos a member, I can list attributes about the group but nothing shows me the name of the actual group.  Anyone have links or information about how I can get this.

I have already look at Googles API site before someone adds the link:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/groups/groups-app

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/groups/group

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-groups-settings

If anyone has a link or informatin on how to do this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I must admit I never use this but perhaps it will help [Admin SDK](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/search-groups) if not sorry .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want can be achieved by using the `AdminGroupsSettings` advanced service.

You need to turn the **Groups Settings API** service on by going to your project's *Resources* > *Advanced Google services...*

[image: advanced google services]

Afterwards, look for the **Groups Settings API** in the list and activate it. As it can be seen on the third column, you can call the service by using `AdminGroupsSettings`.

[image: groups settings api]

Then, just use the below snippet

```
function getGroup() {
  var groupName = AdminGroupsSettings.Groups.get('EMAIL_ADDRESS').name;
  console.log(groupName);
}
```

#### Reference

- [Advanced Google Services Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced);
- [Directory API Groups:get](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/groups/get).

Comment: Appreciate the reference links.  Very simple thank you so much!