# How do you leave a googlegroup via the Googlescript API

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-groups-api

What I am trying to do is leave a googlegroup by utilizing the API rather then having to click on the group itself. This is not shown in the API documentation located here: [Google Groups API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/groups/group#getgroups)

In trying to find a way to leave a group via the API I did find out I was a member of different groups that I did not join but it appears there is no documented way of leaving them. Going here: [Enum Role](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/groups/role). This allows me to see what role I have within a group and the corresponding code used is below.

There is a Enterprise Admin API for removing a group membership but this is not a Enterprise setup and thus AdminGroupSettings cannot be used in this scope.

```
function getGroupNames() {

  try {
      var groups = GroupsApp.getGroups();
  }
  catch(err) {
      console.log("Permission error [getGroup]: Cannot access group members list!");
  }
  
  for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
    var group = groups[i];
    var currentUser = Session.getActiveUser();
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62801809/in-google-app-scripts-how-can-you-get-the-group-name-with-the-group-email
    // Groups Settings API/AdminGroupSettings
    // var groupName = AdminGroupsSettings.Groups.get('unsubscribe-me500@arefilled.site').name;
    // console.log("Attempting to get group name: " + groupName + " from address " + groups[i]);
    if (group.getRole(currentUser.getEmail()) == GroupsApp.Role.MEMBER){
        // How to leave group??
        console.log('You are a member of ' + group.getEmail()); 
        continue;
    }
    if (group.getRole(group.getEmail()) == GroupsApp.Role.INVITED){
        // leave group
        console.log('You are invited to ' + group.getEmail());
        continue;
    }
    if (group.getRole(group.getEmail()) == GroupsApp.Role.MANAGER){
        console.log('You are manager of ' + group.getEmail());
        continue;
    }
    if (group.getRole(group.getEmail()) == GroupsApp.Role.OWNER){
        // leave group
        console.log('You are owner of ' + group.getEmail());
        continue;
    }    
      if (group.getRole(group.getEmail()) == GroupsApp.Role.PENDING){
        // leave group
        console.log('You are pending to ' + group.getEmail());
        continue;
    }
  }

}
```

Is it possible to leave a group via Google Groups API? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*You need to use the Admin SDK Directory API to remove a member from a group.*

#### More Infomation:

The Directory API has a [members.delete](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/members/delete) method which allows you to remove a member from a Google Group.

In Apps Script, you will need to add the `AdminDirectory` Advanced service to the project, and specify the `groupKey` of the group and the `membersKey` of the member you wish to remove in the request:

```js
const groupKey = "XXXXXXXXX"
const memberKey = "YYYYYY"

AdminDirectory.Members.remove(groupKey, memberKey)
```

A successful deletion will result in an `HTTP 204` reponse.

**NB:** You need to run this code as a domain Admin. It is not possible to remove a member from a Google Group via the API without using the Admin SDK.

Comment: So what your saying is that it is not possible to leave a group that is not in a workspace and google intentionally left out this functionality? I already knew about the AdminDirectory but that is for Workspaces accounts and not domain work connected  accounts. The intention was to remove oneself from a group that it says you are a member of. I have several that keep showing up but do not allow me to remove. They are listed from the API itself and are not searchable on the groups page.